# Crystal Report - Add bottom margin on all pages for the text object with 'can grow' parameter active

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a text object in the Detail Section, which has 'Can grow' parameter active. So when I have text in the field, which does not fit in one page, it adds more pages, and continues the text there.

However, when I have long text, and it takes more than one page to fill in the section, I want to add a bottom margin on each page.

When I activate 'maximum number of line' parameter, it displays the set amount of lines, but the rest of the text does not continue on the other page. So it limits with one page.
I need to add a bottom margin / whitespace before switching to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsuppress the page footer section, and set its height to the desired margin.